# GPG having trouble

Tags: gnupg

Im having trouble with GPG.

I downloaded a public key saved it with gedit and imported it.

Now i have the public key but not a secret key.

How can i import also the secret key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why should you give someone his private key? Either you have the private key or not.

- To decrypt your own private message, you need your public key.
- To decrypt your public message, you need your private key.
- To decrypt a message of your friend, you need the public key of your friend.

<sub>More information [on Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography)</sub>

Comment: Im trying to decrypt a message. I have the secret key, but i i think im using a wrong command.

Comment: @Tubuntu Who encrypts the message?

Comment: My friend has encrypted the message.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: I have the public key of my friend, i imported the public key. When i run gpg --list-keys, it says that i have the public key, his name is listed with a public key and a sub key. Now when i try to decrypt a message, it says that i dont have the secret key, but it does show what kind of secret key i must have?

Comment: Use the public key of your friend.

Comment: What kind of command could i use to include the public key of him?

Comment: @Tubuntu Be fair, ask a new question. It's good for your reputation. :)